# Centering span with text in div with button in it

Tags: html, css

My code looks like this:

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button style="float:left;" onclick="openNav()">
            Osoby
        </button>
  <span>
            Antoni Jankowski
        </span>
</div>
```

Unfortunately `text-align:center` makes it center only in the remaining space not taken by the button so its position a little too far to the right. Is it possible to just make it ignore a button? Or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
**Try this**
```

Use `"display: flex"` property to avoid *alignment* and *spacing* issues. **Advantages:** There is *no text limit* for Button & Span tag.

```html
<h1>Try this</h1>
    <div style="display:flex; align-items: flex-start;">
      <button style="flex-shrink:0; margin-right:6px">
        This is your Button
      </button>
      <span style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; justify-content: center;">
        Center Text in span tag
      </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Please add some details in your answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating, use absolute and relative positioning. Absolutely positioning the button will remove it from the flow of the document and not affect the span being centered with respect to the div.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <button>
            Osoby
        </button>
  <span>
            Antoni Jankowski
        </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Thanks for all your help!!